# Video Inserted to HTML web page

Tags: html, css, video

I'm new to HTML and i'm currently building a site based on a template. I'm trying to insert a video but when i paste the URL of the video(youtube, save and then refresh, the page's field in which the video should be is blank white and if i right click it says "Video is not loaded". My HTML code for the video is:

```
<object class="alignimages" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:420px; height:315px;" data="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Y8QxOjuYHg">
        <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Y8QxOjuYHg" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
```

I have tried other things too, without any success. Any ideas?

Comment: You could just use the embed code generated by YouTube for you.

Comment: Have you tried any other youtube videos?   this particular one states "embedding disabled by request"

Comment: I've tried some videos without luck. If you would like to upload a random video what parameter of the above would you change. I'm sorry about the silly questions, but this is my first work on HTML5/CSS and i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: What if you use `https://www.youtube.com/embed/-Y8QxOjuYHg` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add youtube video to your site is to implement it with an iframe element.
When looking at the video, click "share", "embed" and copy/paste the code into your html file

Also, remember to always close your tags.

```
<object>
    ...
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used the Object tag before but i could give some alternative solutions :

First case, if you can get the video file, I'd do this :

```
<video id="video" controls>
    <source src="./video/video.ogv"/>
    <source src="./video/video.mp4"/>
    <source src="./video/video.webm"/>
</video>
```

It's a simple HTML5 video tag. Works fine.

OR, second case, you could do this if you don't want to download the video, you could find another video that allows embetting and you could do this (I found it for you ;) ) :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ui21On1RWjA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the html5 parameter. Below snippet should work for you:

```
<object width="420" height="315">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-Y8QxOjuYHg?html5=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;version=3"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<embed width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-Y8QxOjuYHg?html5=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;version=3" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
```